# My Mathstack reputation decreased without any reason.

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

My Mathstack reputation decreased without any reason. Can anyone explain this action? A reason of this would be very much appreciable!!!

**before**[image: before]

**after**[image: after]

**reputation page**[image: reputation page]

Comment: Chances are something got deleted or a user was removed. Look at your reputation tag https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation and tick "show removed posts" at the end. Maybe this will turn up a post that was deleted.

Comment: @quid I did it now... I think it is because of other user removed their post (sad), although none of that are from today though....

Comment: Since it's 15 points, and there's no entry in your reputation tab, my guess is that somebody accepted an answer of you and then some time later decided to accept a different answer. An unacceptance only creates an entry in the reputation tab if enough time has passed between acceptance and unacceptance. (I don't know how much time is needed, maybe there must be a midnight [UTC] in between.)

Comment: @DanielFischer I think that reason may be right.

Comment: You do know that *everyone* can see the redacted details just by going to your profile, right? And I mean everyone. You don't even have to be logged in, or even registered.

Comment: I said it because it came across as odd, redacting the names of the posts, where this information is freely available and easily accessible.

Comment: @AsafKaragila okk, I did not know that! Do not see much other profiles that much ..., I know now though, thanks!

Comment: The only information that is worth redacting is posts which *you* have downvoted (specifically answers, which will show in the reputation log) and perhaps posts that were deleted (although that is probably less crucial).

Comment: I actually know now who un-accepted my answer... (don't khow why did that though)

Comment: To add to @AsafKaragila's point about details which are publicly visible, I will add that once you check  "show removed posts" then the profile might start look differently for you and for other users viewing it.